# How is voice processed in Elliott Smith's Angeles?

Tags: production

I've been wondering how is the voice processed in [Elliot Smith's song Angeles](https://youtu.be/FMSU4QDbdew).

My guess is that it's duplicated (maybe recorded twice? That would already make them a little different) and then eqed differently, and pitch altered a bit differently on each channel.

I'd like to know if there's someone who could confirm this or complete it. Is it some known technique I'm not familiar with? If anyone has any sources where I could watch or read on similar approaches, I'd be thankful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From https://tapeop.com/interviews/118/recording-elliott-smiths-either-or/

> The [first two solo] records were totally limited, and there was no
>   choice about what to use [gear-wise]. Then I got an 8-track [Tascam
>   38], and I had a choice between a couple of different mics. I got a
>   compressor [Behringer Composer] and one of those [digital effects]
>   boxes that will make any effect that you have the patience to try to
>   program [Digitech TSR 24S]. Most of [Either/Or] was done at my house,
>   some was done at Joanna's house on a 4-track, and some on 16-track in
>   California...

So it looks like most of Either/Or the album that Angeles was on, was recorded with his Tascam 38. He always layers his voices though there's nothing too special about it, so either overdub or a separate track. Not sure why he used a Tascam 38, that's super old. Like 1982 old. Elliott Smith was a genius though, so he must've had his reasons.